# How to install Zimbra certification?

Tags: ssl, zimbra

I have this error when I want install a commercial SSL in Zimbra

> Your certificate was not installed due to the error : system failure:
>     exception executing command: zmcertmgr verifycrtkey comm
>    /opt/zimbra/mailboxd/webapps/zimbraAdmin/tmp/current_comm.key
>    /opt/zimbra/mailboxd/webapps/zimbraAdmin/tmp/current.crt with
>    {RemoteManager: mail.mydomain.com->zimbra@mail.mydomain.com:22}

Comment: no answer? please help if you know

Comment: You can install certification LetsEncrypt. And link for help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x2YPGcN3qHs

Answer (score 2):

Use below script for SSL install in Zimbra.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

# SSL certificate installation in Zimbra
# with SSL certificate provided by Let's Encrypt (letsencrypt.org)
# Author: Subhash (serverkaka.com)

# Check if running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

read -p 'letsencrypt_email [xx@xx.xx]: ' letsencrypt_email
read -p 'mail_server_url [xx.xx.xx]: ' mail_server_url

# Check All variable have a value
if [ -z $mail_server_url ] || [ -z $letsencrypt_email ]
then
      echo run script again please insert all value. do not miss any value
else

# Installation start
# Stop the jetty or nginx service at Zimbra level
su - zimbra -c 'zmproxyctl stop'
su - zimbra -c 'zmmailboxdctl stop'

# Install git and letsencrypt
cd /opt/
apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
cd letsencrypt

# Get SSL certificate
./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone --non-interactive --agree-tos --email $letsencrypt_email -d $mail_server_url --hsts
cd /etc/letsencrypt/live/$mail_server_url
cat <<EOF >>chain.pem
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
EOF

# Verify commercial certificate
mkdir /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/$mail_server_url/* /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/
chown zimbra:zimbra /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/*
ls -la /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/
su - zimbra -c 'cd /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/ && /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr verifycrt comm privkey.pem cert.pem chain.pem'

# Deploy the new Let's Encrypt SSL certificate
cp -a /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra.$(date "+%Y%m%d")
cp /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/privkey.pem /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/commercial.key
sudo chown zimbra:zimbra /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/commercial.key
su - zimbra -c 'cd /opt/zimbra/ssl/letsencrypt/ && /opt/zimbra/bin/zmcertmgr deploycrt comm cert.pem chain.pem'

# Restart Zimbra
su - zimbra -c 'zmcontrol restart'

# setting auto https redirect
cd /opt && touch https-redirect.sh && chown zimbra:zimbra https-redirect.sh && chmod +x https-redirect.sh
cat <<EOF >>/opt/https-redirect.sh
zmprov ms $mail_server_url zimbraReverseProxyMailMode redirect
EOF
su - zimbra -c '/opt/https-redirect.sh'
rm /opt/https-redirect.sh
fi
```

For more reference check this link: https://github.com/SubhashPatel/Install-Zimbra-mail-server-ubuntu/blob/master/configure-ssl-zimbra.sh

Answer (score 1):

You should try using CLI to install SSL certificate for Zimbra. Also you need to verify that you have the same certificate which you have downloaded from the certificate authority.

For `commercial.crt` you need to copy one certificate downloaded from the authority. For `commercial_ca.crt`, there must be one CA bundle file, you will have from certificate authority.

Private key, you need to verify during generating your CSR and also verify with the hosting. After that restart the Zimbra by command

```
zmcontrol restart
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution.
you shouldn't fill the subject alternative name when you want create csr!
thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Every other year I spend hours on renewing the ssl certificates on zimbra with the help of hopeless outdated tutorials. A tedious process that I don't do often enough to remember how I did it. I learned the hard way that it is easier to use the admin console, than using CLI and messing around with concatinating the different certificates.

Hereby the steps that I take:

Please note that this is a walkthrough, dedicated to the
GoGetSSL Sectigo PositiveSSL Wildcard certificate, and may not work for other SSL providers.

Zimbra version: 8.8.15

1. We use the wildcard certificate on several servers, but we generate the CSR always(!) on the zimbra server. So go to admin console > Configure > Certificates, click the domain in the list and then in top right corner, choose install certificate. Choose the generate CSR option (second of the 3 options). Make sure that in the common name field you use the wildcard symbol: e.g.
   *.example.com
   Also check the checkbox that it concerns a wildcard common name
   Fill out the rest of the info according to your situation. At the bottom, there's option to add other names; remove all of them (if any). Go to next page and download the CSR, finish the wizard.
2. on the GoGetSSL page create the new/renew the SSL certificate with the by Zimbra generated CSR. Finish up the entire process, including the validation. All the way up to that the certificate is issued and files can be downloaded. Choose to download the 'All files' zip file. extract on your local system.
3. browse to: https://www.gogetssl.com/wiki/intermediate-certificates/sectigo-intermediate-root-certificates/
   On this page download the file: DV RSA Files > RSA DV Bundle with SHA-1 (TXT file)
4. go back to admin console > Configure > Certificates, click the domain in the list and then in top right corner, choose install certificate. This time you choose the 3rd option: install commercial signed certificate. First screen of the wizard shows the info you entered earlier for the CSR. The info may show up empty. For me this didn't give me any problems, so I left it. On the next screen: You have to upload 3 certificate files by default, but we need to upload 4, so we need to do Add Intermediate CA for the fourth file.

Choose files as follows:

- Certificate: server certificate from the zip file: e.g. _example.com.crt
- Root CA: RSA DV Bundle with SHA-1 (TXT file), from the link above
- Intermediate CA: USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt from zip file
- (Added) Intermediate CA: AAA_Certificate_Services.crt

NOTE: I can't remember which Intermediate CA I chose first, so if any problems, try switching the last 2 mentioned files around.

Finish the wizard and test by sending and receiving email.

Then I take the certificates and update other servers with these certificates. (e.g. nginx, apache2, etc). Note: you may need to get the commercial.key file for use on other servers. On linux this file is located in: /opt/zimbra/ssl/zimbra/commercial/
If permission denied, you may use root account or do: sudo su - zimbra

I hope this helps for people struggling with the same certificate and zimbra